# How to add next previous in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How I can add next previous in wordpress I have this html

```
<div class="mu-blog-navigation">
<a class="mu-blog-nav-btn mu-blog-nav-prev" href="#"><span class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></span>Previous Post</a>
<a class="mu-blog-nav-btn mu-blog-nav-next" href="#">Next Post<span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

The 'posts_nav_link' tag creates two links at the bottom of the page within the WordPress Loop to display the next and previous pages in chronological order.

```
<div class="navigation">
    <p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','Previous Post','Next Post'); ?></p>
</div>
```

The parameters of the tag are as follows:

`<?php posts_nav_link('separator','prelabel','nextlabel'); ?>`

You can also use the `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` tags.

Hope this helps.